# Memory leak error?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

For a simple assignment to do with dynamic memory and copy constructors, my prof has assigned us a simple assignment, but I get an error during the second time my `delete []` happens.

header file:

```
class Stream {
    int len;
    char *hold;
    char* newmem(int);
public:
    Stream ();
    Stream (int);
    Stream(const char *);
    ~Stream ( );
    void operator=(const Stream &);
    Stream(const Stream &);
    friend void show(Stream);
    void operator<<(const char*);
};
```

it should be fairly simple. here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "stream.h"

char* Stream::newmem(int x) {
    char * tmp;
    try {
        tmp = new char[x];
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc) {
        tmp = NULL;
    }
    if(tmp)
        cout << "newmem:  " << (void *) tmp << endl;
    return tmp;
}

Stream::Stream ( ) {
    len = 1000;
    hold = newmem(len);
    if (hold)
        strcpy (hold, "");
}

Stream::Stream(int n) {
    len = n;
    hold = newmem(len);
    if (hold)
        strcpy (hold,"");
}

Stream::Stream(const char * dat) {
    len = strlen(dat) +1;
    hold = newmem(len);
    if (hold)
        strcpy(hold,dat);
}

Stream::Stream(const Stream &from) {
    cout << "in the copy constructor, allocating new memory..." << endl;
    cout << "original pointer address is: " << (void *) from.hold << endl;
    cin.get( );

    len=from.len;
    hold=newmem(len +1);
    cout << "new pointer address is: " << (void *) hold << endl;
    cin.get( );

    if(hold)
        strcpy (hold,from.hold);
}

Stream::~Stream ( ) {
    cout << "destruct:  " << (void *) hold << endl;
    cin.get( );
    if (hold)
        delete [] hold;
}

void Stream::operator= (const Stream &from) {
    if(hold)
        delete [ ] hold;
    len = from.len;
    hold=newmem(len +1);
    if (hold)
        strcpy(hold,from.hold);
}

void show (Stream prt) {
    cout << "String is: " << prt.hold << endl << "Length is: " << prt.len << endl;
}

void Stream::operator<< (const char *data) {
    int dlen = strlen(data);
    for (int i=0 ; i<=len && i<=dlen ; i++) {
        hold[i] = data[i];
    }
}

int main( ) {
   char data[ ] = "Growing up it all seems so one-sided;"
                  "Opinions all provided;"
                  "The future pre-decided;"
                  "Detached and subdivided;"
                  "In the mass production zone!"
                  "-Neil Peart- \"Subdivisions\"";

   Stream x1, x2(25), x3;
   x1 << data;
   x2 << data;
   show(x1);
   show(x2);

   x3 = x2;
   show(x3);

   return 0;
}
```

and my output / error:

```
in the copy constructor, allocating new memory...
original pointer address is: 0x804c008

new pointer address is: 0x804c808

String is: Growing up it all seems so one-sided;Opinions all provided;The future pre-decided;Detached and subdivided;In the mass production zone!-Neil Peart-Subdivisions"
Length is: 1000
destruct:  0x804c808


in the copy constructor, allocating new memory...
original pointer address is: 0x804c3f8

new pointer address is: 0x804c808

String is: Growing up it all seems so
Length is: 25
destruct:  0x804c808

*** glibc detected *** a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804c808 ***
```

Comment: Be aware that the `operator<<` has an off-by-one error when dlen > len, and does not copy the terminator '\0' then. strncpy avoids both problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a little self-help advice: The most important tool for catching memory access errors is `valgrind`. Run it on your program, and you'll get a warning every time you try to access unallocated or uninitialized memory. It's no substitute for knowledge, but the next best thing.

While I get different output than you get, errors seem to interact here:

1. The `operator<<` has an off-by-one error in the range check. It writes one byte too much (`hold[len]`).
2. `operator<<` does never write the terminating null byte. Both errors are invoked by `x2 << data`.
3. When the copy constructor tries to copy the string from `x2`, `strcpy` finds no terminating null byte and both reads right off the end of `x2.hold` and writes past the end of `x3.hold`. The latter has the potential for unbounded corruption and probably caused your error.

Whenever you deal with C strings, make very, very sure to get termination right. The fixed version is:

```
void Stream::operator<< (const char *data) {
    int dlen = strlen(data);
    hold[len-1] = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i < len-1 && i <= dlen ; i++) {
         hold[i] = data[i];
    }
}
```

Or, using the std library:

```
void Stream::operator<< (const char *data) {
    strncpy(hold, data, len);
    hold[len-1] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The for loop in the `operator<<` has *two* off-by-one errors:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=len
```

allows `i==len`, but the only valid indices of `hold` are `0..(len-1)`. So, you can write one off the end.

Secondly, as thiton pointed out, it doesn't copy the `\0` terminator even if there is space.

---

A correct implementation might look like:

```
void Stream::operator<< (const char *data) {
    int source_len = strlen(data);
    int copy_len = min(source_len, len-1); // allow for terminator

    for (int i=0; i<copy_len; i++) {
        hold[i] = data[i];
    }
    hold[copy_len] = '\0';
}
```

although it'd be better practise to simply use `strncpy`.

---

Note that the idiom of using half-open (or one-past-the-end) ranges is standard not only in direct array indexing, but also with C++ iterators. So, you should always expect to see

```
for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
```

or

```
for (i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
```

and should generally treat closed-range loops like yours as a smell that warrants further investigation.

Comment: i tried using this, but i get 
"*** glibc detected *** a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804c808 ***
*** glibc detected *** a.out: malloc: top chunk is corrupt: 0x0804c820 ***"

Comment: it's possible there's another error I missed - try running your program under valgrind to identify where the damage is done

Comment: i used the one that Thiton posted and it worked! thank you guys so much. very nice community here. thanks!